# Symfony2 - Custom annotation loading

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I'd like to make a custom annotation which is loaded like the Route annotation. I have found tutorials for annotations so that's not the problem. The problem I have is with the loading behavior.

I'd like to set for my custom annotation like this:

```
customannotation:
    resource: "Bundle\Controller\Class"
```

Then I'd like to get something like the RouteCollection which I can work with. The loading of the annotations should happen when the routes get loaded or nearly the same time.

Symfony 2.7
PHP 5.6.9

Comment: You can create a bundle, make a bundleconfiguration to add the key `customannotation`, then in the bundle extension you can do whatever you want

Comment: I know that already. The Configuration is also no problem the only problem is to load the annotations from classes similar to the routing

Comment: You should look into `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry`

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at the AnnotationRegistry.

Comment: Formatting. Spelling. Grammar.